# Have some doubts in this python program (PRIME or NOT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

So, I wrote a code to find if a number is PRIME or NOT...

I wrote it in 2 different ways, they are almost same but I just had a doubt. So here it is:

1st code:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
lim = num//2 + 1
for i in range(2,lim):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("Prime!")
        break
else:
    print("Not Prime!")
```

2nd Code:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for i in range(2,num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("Prime!")
        break
else:
    print("Not Prime!")
```

The 1st code takes the input(num) and according to the input sets a limit(which is the half number + 1)
and then checks if the num is divisible by all the numbers in range (2 to lim)

The second one is same but instead of setting a limit it just checks all numbers lower than the input, which means it has to do a little more work...

Now both of these are almost same, the only difference is I saved a line in 2nd one and output efficiency is also better!

Which code would you want me to prefer/

also if this code has any problems, pointing them out would be helpful!
Thanks :)

Comment: First one - efficiency is a coincidence - also, your else is placed in a really awkward position. Use a Boolean, such as `isprime` and then check false if it isn't, then finally print based on that.

Comment: Kindly ellaborate!

Comment: I added it as an answer - hopefully it helps

Comment: Both are terribly inefficient compared to stopping at the floor(sqrt(num)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

The most important piece of iteration, namely determining whether a number is prime or not, is to keep track of it. Without this process and in the OP's program, a variable is not used to handle this, meaning that he checks whether a number is or isn't prime *every single time* and concludes at that point. He also uses an `else` statement which is syntactically incorrect.

To prevent this, we can use a variable to keep track of this. Let's call it `isprime`. We need to assume that a number will always be a prime unless otherwise said. This can be achieved by setting `isprime` to default be `True`, and setting it to be `False` when we conclude that it is not a prime, because is has a divisor. Finally, we can check this variable at the end and determine whether that number is a prime or not, because it would be set to `False` if not, or left as `True` if it is.

Another observation made is that the limit for determining primes can be reduced down to `sqrt(n)`. This is because we do not need to find every factor if it exists, just its lowest corresponding factor. Let's look at an example:

Factors of 24: 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12

We can stop checking for the factors right here:

2, 3, 4 | 6, 8, 12, 24

This is because if a number has a factor (such as greater than the square root), it will have a corresponding factor less than the square root. As a result, we can set our limit to be `sqrt(n)`, just for peace of mind + a time complexity of `O(sqrt(n))` v. `O(n)`.

As an extra note, `sqrt` is not inbuilt into Python. You will have to import it from the `math` library using:

```
from math import sqrt
```

## Final Code

```
# Setup
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
lim = sqrt(num)
isprime = True

# Loop & check
for i in range(2,lim):
    if num % i == 0:
        isprime = False
        break

# Results
if isprime:
    print("Prime!")
else:
    print("Not prime!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the solution is wrong. You gave to switch the "Prime" and "Not Prime" tags. Like follows;

```
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
lim = num//2 + 1
for i in range(2,lim):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("Not Prime!")
        break
else:
    print("Prime!")
```

> The solution 1 is more efficient because you do not need to do extra
> computation to check num//2 + 1. So it is preferable.

Comment: you said solution 1 is preferable...
but is there any issue in the 2nd code?
or is it just it will need more computational power?

Comment: They are essentially same, you also need to do swapping there. For numbers that are not prime and divisible let's say 2 or 3. The loop immediately breaks and gives you the impression that it is more efficient because you skipped the assignment of lim variable (save you 0.000xxx seconds of computation). On the other hand try to search for 8 and 9 digit primes and put them in your functions where it will approximately take twice as much in the second code. Also, I advise you to search for isprime function for optimized implementation if you don't need to implement yourself.